# why am I getting this erroneous output?

Tags: java, arrays, list

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-arraylist/probleminput

5

5 41 77 74 22 44

1 12

4 37 34 36 52

0

3 20 22 33

5

1 3

3 4

3 1

4 3

5 5

Sample Output

74

52

37

ERROR!

ERROR!

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    ArrayList array[] = new ArrayList[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        int no = sc.nextInt();
        while(no != '\n')
        {
             list.add(no);
             no = sc.nextInt(); 
        }
        array[i] = list;
    }

    int k = sc.nextInt();
    int l = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(array[k].get(l));
}

}
```

Error (stderr)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)

at Solution.main(Solution.java:18)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve via this program?

Comment: @NicholasK ive given that demo in the above section ..

Comment: @LanaLightman link given above doesn't work anymore, can you update the question with original question from [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-arraylist/probleminput)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the problem  correctly it should take first int then scan the n lines and creating sort of 2 dimension list/array or so then should accept int of questions about what is in position (x,y) in this 2 dimensional object covering what is out of bounds as an "ERROR!".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT.
     * Your class should be named Solution.
     */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    ArrayList array[] = new ArrayList[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        Scanner linSc = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
        while (linSc.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(linSc.nextInt());
        }
        linSc.close();
        array[i] = list;
    }
    n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int l = sc.nextInt();
            try {
                System.out.println(array[k - 1].get(l));
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```